Airflow Task Fails with Log Access Error and Celery Executor Not Accessible
I am setting up Apache Airflow with Celery Executor for orchestration tasks, and I'm encountering two issues that I suspect are related. I have a test DAG that simply prints "hello," but the task consistently fails. Additionally, I'm unable to access the Celery Flower UI on http://localhost:5555, despite RabbitMQ showing received messages, suggesting that the Celery workers are active but may not be executing tasks as expected.
When I attempt to view the logs for the failed task in the Airflow Web UI, I receive the following error:
*** Could not read served logs: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.
This issue seems to indicate a misconfiguration with how logs are served, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. My setup involves the following key configuration files:
1.airflow.cfg

[core]
executor = CeleryExecutor
dags_folder = /opt/airflow/dags
fernet_key = x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x00xx0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x=

[logging]
# The folder where your Airflow logs will be stored
base_log_folder = /opt/airflow/logs

# Log files for the scheduler
scheduler_log_file = /opt/airflow/logs/scheduler.log

# Log files for the webserver
webserver_log_file = /opt/airflow/logs/webserver.log

# Log files for the workers
worker_log_file = /opt/airflow/logs/worker.log

[webserver]
secret_key = xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo
worker_timeout = 600
expose_config = True
base_url = http://0.0.0.0:8080

[database]

sql_alchemy_conn=postgresql+psycopg2://test:*********@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:5432/testdwh


[celery]

broker_url = amqps://dgsqs:******************@kangaroo.rmq.cloudamqp.com/dgsqs
result_backend = db+postgresql://test:*********@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:5432/testdwh #using the same db could this be a problem?

# Other configurations...
worker_concurrency = 16


2.dockerfile

# Use the official Airflow image as the base
FROM apache/airflow:2.6.1

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt
RUN pip install flower

RUN mkdir -p /opt/airflow/logs && chown -R airflow: /opt/airflow/logs
RUN pip install supervisor

ENV AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False

COPY dags /opt/airflow/dags

COPY airflow.cfg /opt/airflow/airflow.cfg

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

USER root
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
USER airflow

# Run the entrypoint script
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]


3.entrypoint.sh

#!/bin/bash

# Initialize the database
airflow db init


# Run the supervisor to manage the Airflow processes
exec supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf


4.supervisord.conf

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:airflow-webserver]
command=airflow webserver --worker-timeout 600
priority=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:airflow-scheduler]
command=airflow scheduler
priority=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true


also attaching screenshot of the test dag run in the local airflow UI  and the dag code.Would be great if somebody could help me out here please

Hello! i cannot access the logs from airflow worker in another server, do you have any idea?
